# How to configure RubyMine with LiveEdit and live css preview

Tags: css, wysiwyg, rubymine

I am not able to setup RubyMine with LiveEdit plugin to preview changes to my SASS files. Whenever I modify html.rb file in views it reloads the page, which is great. However when I modify sass files, no live preview is available. Anyone succeeded with it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would need to configure your SASS environment to create source maps and, in turn, enable source maps in Google Chrome (I am not sure if other browsers support source maps).

Then you would be able to directly edit the SASS files in Chrome and your compiler should be able to notice the changes accordingly.

A great tutorial that should help you get everything set up is here:

http://snugug.com/musings/debugging-sass-source-maps